# How to make shadow for circle cropped image in glide 4

Tags: android, android-glide

My profile image that made rounded with `RoundedCorners` method in glid4 is very flatted and my profile it has not any shadow. How can i set shadow to my image profile ?glid4 hase any method for this or i have to create one?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate Solution:-

Use a custom drawable and set it to imageview background `shadow.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
              <solid android:color="@color/gray"/>
                <!--shadow Color-->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
             <solid android:color="@color/lightgrey"/>//your background color here
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Use it like this way:-

```
android:background="@drawable/shadow"
```

Another solution u can try :-
https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

This library can be used for your requirement

Comment: using layer-list is the best option!

Answer (score 3):

*implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0"*

**XML**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_image"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_circle_background"
    android:elevation="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_item_employee"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        tools:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Shape drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
     <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```

**Glide Configuration**

```
Glide.with(this)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(item.image)
    .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
    .into(iv_item_employee)
```